# Logstash Grok custom URIPATHPARAM

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

How can I split URIPATHPARAM in grok filter.

Here is my grok pattern.

```
      grok {
            match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} (?:%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int}|-) %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} \"(?:%{WORD:verb}|-) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:request}|-) (?:HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}|-( )?)\" \"%{DATA:userAgent}\"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?"]
  }

            grok {
                    match => [ "request", "%{URIPROTO:http_protocol}://(?:%{USER:user}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST:refhost})?(?:%{URIPATHPARAM:uri_param})?" ]
            }
```

}

Values coming in URI_param

```
/a1/post/abcxyz/data/adfs/
/partner/uc/article/adafdf?adfaf
```

I want to catch first three strings of above url's in separate field e.g.

> /a1/post/abcxyz
>
> /partner/uc/article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  grok {
     match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} (?:%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int}|-) %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} \"(?:%{WORD:verb}|-) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:request}|-) (?:HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}|-( )?)\" \"%{DATA:userAgent}\"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?"]
  }

  grok {
     match => [ "request", "%{URIPROTO:http_protocol}://(?:%{USER:user}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST:refhost})?(?:%{URIPATHPARAM:uri_param})?" ]
  }
  if [uri_param] {
    mutate {
     split => { "uri_param" => "/"}
     add_field => { "uri_param_1" => "%{[uri_param][1]}" }
     add_field => { "uri_param_2" => "%{[uri_param][2]}" }
     add_field => { "uri_param_3" => "%{[uri_param][3]}" }
   }
  }
```

Or Alternately, You could just grab these three params from grok itself. 
like

```
  grok {
     match => [ "request", "%{URIPROTO:http_protocol}://(?:%{USER:user}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST:refhost})?(?:/%{WORD:uri_param_1}/%{WORD:uri_param_2}/%{WORD:uri_param_3}/%{GREEDYDATA:other_params})?" ]
  }
```

As asked by you, to join them again, you can simply use mutate filter:

```
 mutate {
   add_field => { "uri_param" => "/%{[uri_param_1]}/%{[uri_param_2]}/%{[uri_param_3]}/%{[other_params]}"}
 }
```

I hope that will work, just test it out, and let me know if that worked for you or not.

Comment: Thanks!! Your alternate solution works for me. Also How can I merge them in single field.

Answer (score 0):

use the grokpattern below on the uri_param field

```
%{THREESTRINGS:newField}
```

where the custom pattern for THREESTRINGS is

```
THREESTRINGS \/\b\w+\b\/\b\w+\b\/\b\w+\b
```